# Converting file path to URI

Tags: ruby

I have a string that represents a file path, such as "/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/name.ext". Now I'd like to convert it to a legal URI (a string starting with "file://" and so on).

How do I do it in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.join('file:///', '/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/name.ext')
 => #<URI::Generic:0x0000000263fcc0 URL:file:/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/name.ext>

uri.scheme
 => "file"
uri.path
 => "/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/name.ext"
uri.to_s
 => "file:/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/name.ext"
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the result (uri.to_s) illegal? Shouldn't it be "file://home..."?

Comment: @user1372109 It should be `file:///home/...`.  The `file://` part is the scheme, while the third slash is the start of the path.

Comment: It might seem like a bug, so I've opened another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571945/ruby-uri-module-produces-illegal-file-uri

Answer (score 3):

Since Ruby 2.6.3 use can use [URI::File](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/File.html)

```
path = '/somewhere/on/your/drive'
URI::File.build([nil, path])
```

Comment: Note that `path` is a path in the `URI` sense (it can't contain spaces and such), not the in the `File` sense.