# Ruby URI module produces illegal file-URI

Tags: ruby, uri

This is a follow-up question to [Converting file path to URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571562/converting-file-path-to-uri).

Consider:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.join('file:///', '/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/name.ext')
 => #<URI::Generic:0x0000000263fcc0 URL:file:/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/name.ext>

uri.to_s
 => "file:/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/name.ext"
```

Isn't the result illegal? Shoudln't it be `"file://home/..."`, with a double slash?

Comment: I actually think it should be `file:///home/...`.  But does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  `file://home/...` refers to a file on the host named 'home'.  The full syntax is `file:///home/...`, with *three* slashes, where the empty host component indicates the local host. However, most URI parsers that recognize the 'file' scheme also accept `file:/pathname` with only one slash; the lack of doubled slashes means the host component is skipped.

Comment: So this one slash form is unique to the file scheme? Those parsers wouldn't accept the analogous "http:www.something.com", right?

Comment: `http:www.something.com` isn't analogous, because `www.something.com` is the host part.  The http analog would be accepting `http:/foo` as a synonym for `http://localhost/foo`, but I don't know of anything that does that offhand.